# Cors-Header missing when Video comes from Browser-Cache

Tags: html, amazon-s3, video, cors

I have a couple of video-requests to an s3-bucket. the last two are cached. 
[image]

Every not cached request had the expected cors-headers:
[image]

Once the video is cached, the cors-headers are missing and it comes to the well known cors-policy error:
[image]

It's only reproduceable in windows-chrome, everything works fine on my mac.
Does anyone have the same problem? Is it a browser-bug or am I able to set anything in the bucket to prevent this problem?

Comment: Have you found a solutions for this? (Maybe other way than add "cache breaking" property?)

Comment: Hi @OlesSavluk, we didn't found a solution for this.
We reported this as bug to google and are still waiting for response.

A cache breaking property in the query string is not an option, the error happens via js when a user watches videos one after another and returns to an already viewed one, then it's not working anymore.